# Nginx force http traffic to https not working

Tags: nginx

I have a site and it was redirecting traffic to https, but all of sudden is not, I have looked at my .conf file and everything seems in order, I have been banging my head on a wall trying to solve this, but everything seems right, am I missing something here?

```
# Proxy upstream to the node process
upstream node {
    server mydomain.upstream:80;
}


# Configuration for Nginx
server {
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    expires -1;


    location /{
        proxy_set_header x-real-ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header x-nginX-proxy true;
        proxy_read_timeout          120s;
        proxy_pass         http://node;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com-0002/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com-0002/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot



    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;;
    } # managed by Certbot


    # Redirect non-https traffic to https
    # if ($scheme != "https") {
    #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # } # managed by Certbot


}

server {
        server_name mydomain.ca www.mydomain.ca;

        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        expires -1;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header x-real-ip $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header x-nginX-proxy true;
                proxy_read_timeout          120s;
                proxy_pass         http://node;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.ca-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.ca-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

   if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   } # managed by Certbot




}

server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.ca) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mydomain.ca) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot








}


server {
    if ($host = mydomain.ca) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name mydomain.ca www.mydomain.ca;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: Try pairing down your config and save it as a temp file. Then run nginx with the config option pointing to your experiment. If it works, start adding back things until it fails.